# iOS - How can I sort the managed objects fetched from CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

This is how i am inserting the data,

```
NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[DOSnow entityDescription] inManagedObjectContext: proxy.managedObjectContext];
DOCurrentCondition *doSnow = [[[DOSnow alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext: proxy.managedObjectContext] autorelease];
NSXMLElement *snowConditionsElement = [[roseElement elementsForName:SNOW] lastObject];
NSArray  *snowElements = [snowConditionsElement children];

for (NSXMLElement *snowElement in snowElements)
{
    NSEntityDescription * entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[DOPair entityDescription] inManagedObjectContext: proxy.managedObjectContext];
    DOPair *pair = [[[DOPair alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext: proxy.managedObjectContext] autorelease];
    pair.key = [snowElement name];
    pair.value = [snowElement stringValue];
    [doSnow addConditionsObject: pair]; 
}
[proxy save];
```

And this is how i am fetching the data,

```
- (NSArray *) fetchSnowConditions
{
    ApplicationFacade *appFacade = [ApplicationFacade appFacade];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appFacade.rProxy.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:[DOSnow entityDescription] inManagedObjectContext:context]];   
    NSError *error;  
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
    return result;
}
```

So i am not getting the data in same order as i inserted.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `[NSFetchRequest setSortDescriptor:]` to get a meaningful ordering of your results. The `NSFetchRequest` documentation doesn't say anything about the default order of the results, so it's not a good idea to assume there is any.

Of course, in order to correctly specify the sort descriptor, you probably need to add a field to your managed objects to sort on, and assign a value to it when creating the objects. It could be an incrementing index field, a creation date, or something like that.